# mongo index field presence

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How can you create an index in mongodb to only index presence of a field (whether it's null/undefined or it actually has a value). I understand null is considered a value, however for this case I would like to consider `null` the same as `undefined` so the index will only care whether the property is `null/undefined` or not.

Example:
I have a data structure with a very big internal property:

```js
document = {
 _id: 1
 info: { /* a fairly large object here */ }
}

index = { info: 1 }
```

If I were to make a query as follows:

```js
collection.find({ info: null })
```

This would work fine in terms of search performance. Issue is that the object is large, so the index ends up very large (hundreds of MB with only 500k documents)

I have looked into conditional indexes (partial and sparse), but they only work if you want to index subset of documents. I want to index all documents but only on the presence of the field, not its entire value

Other practical option is adding a boolean flag `hasInfo: Boolean` and just index that, but will have to back-populate data and keep redundant properties on the collection

Comment: How about indexing a single, common field which present in every `info` objects? say if all `info` object has an `id` field, You may index `info.id`.

Comment: That could work, one problem is if this object has a mixed type and does not have a rigid structure so no property on it can be guaranteed (it can be populated by an error or a result of something).

Comment: I think if a sufficient portion of the `info` object that contains the common field, your performance gain from indexing that field would not have large difference from a perfect one.(i.e. every `info` object have that field). On the other hand, you may just back populate a relatively small amount of the `info` object to make sure every `info` object contains that field.

Comment: You may find [wildcard index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-wildcard/reference/embedded-object-behavior/#wildcard-indexes-on-embedded-objects) useful in your case.